# Make a global validation for all requests in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have to make validation of all of `Date` format only using class/request in `Laravel`. Can I make validation for all of the requests ? I think i do it in `request.php` abstract class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something like this, at first create a `BaseController` like the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(Request $request) {

        $this->request = $request;

        $this->hasValidDate();
    }

    protected function hasValidDate()
    {
        if($this->request->method() == 'POST') {
            // Adjust the rules as needed
            $this->validate($this->request, ['date' => 'required|date']);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your other controllers, extend the `BaseController` like this example:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;

class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Hope you got the idea. Use it wisely.